# Viewing Badge Progress

Tags: discussion, badges

Is there anyway to see your progress on earning quantitative badges?  Like if the badge is looking for a certain number of a specific type of voting, how many you have done, etc. (i.e. Sportsmanship)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen several ways of viewing subsets of your progress towards badges:

- One way is to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/queries) to mine the data dump for the information (possibly using one of the existing queries).
- Another is to get the [Strunk & White](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) badge, which allows you to see review-related badge progress on the [Review page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/)
- As @PirateEric mentions you can also see your Flag Weight on your profile, indicating your progress towards the [Deputy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/65/deputy) and [Marshal](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/74/marshal) badges
- You can also see on your profile the number of consecutive days you've visited the site, which is used for the [Enthusiast](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/22/enthusiast) and [Fanatic](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/23/fanatic) badges
- Lastly, you can see your progress towards the [Strunk & White](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) and [Copy Editor](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/33/copy-editor) badges on your profile under 'Activity' -> 'Suggestions' (as long as you can't do direct edits yet)

Comment: And you can see your flag weight on your profile.

Comment: @PirateEric Added, thanks. Also, grats on getting Deputy. :)

Comment: Thanks, just got it yesterday :-D

Comment: Data explorer is very nice.